# Nested yields preserving each function state

Tags: python, stream, iterator

I have the following client interface:

```
for e in read_stream(): print(e)
```

Where read_stream controls the number of samples to be taken from an infinite stream and yields a value yielded by said stream. Here's an equivalent example of my application:

```
def foo():
    
    internal_state = 0
    
    while True:
        
        num = randint(0,100000)
        
        if num == 7:
            internal_state += 1
            print(internal_state)
            yield num
            
            
def read_stream():
    
    global max_reads
    for reads in range(0,max_reads):
        print("counter=", str(reads))
        num = foo()
        yield next(num)
```

Problem is that when executing `read_stream()` , read_stream() internal variables are preserved, but `foo()` variables are overwritten.

I'm aware that changing the interface might be the most sensible solution here (doing away with the middleman `read_stream()`), but is it possible to execute nested yields in such a manner that all the levels of the hierarchy run their complete cycles without resets?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: move `num= foo()` outside your `for reads in range(...)` loop

Comment: Yup, that works. A bit of a brainfart in retrospective. Thanks.